# Beans validation mutli lang message fail

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm doing a Web application using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, JSF 2.x, JPA 2 with Hibernate Provider. The application run on Tomcat 6.X.

The web-app can be show in different languages : en , es , fr.

I use the bean validation in my entities. Hibernate Validator is the provider, version 4.2.0.Final.

I have the following code in an entity:

```
@Email
    @Size(max=255)
    @Column(name = "email_ceo", length = 255)
    private String emailCeo;

@NotEmpty
    @OrderBy("position ASC")
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "site", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<SiteLanguage> langs;
```

I handle the exception like this:

```
try {
            siteService.createSite(newSite);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            for (ConstraintViolation<?> cv : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
                facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, cv.getMessage(), null));
            }
        }
```

I display the error message in the template by using `<h:messages />`

**How do I get the translated message, because `cv.getMessage()` always return the english message ?**

For the email it works fine, i have the message in good language.

There is a second thing, I don't understand :

**Why `@NotEmpty` throws a ConstraintViolationException and `@Email` doesn't ?**

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use locale.  The way we used to do it is, basically have the locale strings in either language in a table and based on the used locale(en, fr) it grabs it.
2. Catch all exceptions with `catch Exception e` then look at the type that gets thrown.  It will catch it in order and continue from the catch clause.  So, the first exception thrown will exit the try block.

> @Email
>
> field/property. Needs to be a string.
>
> Check whether the specified string is a valid email address.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.html

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure you answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cv.getMessage() use cv.getMessageTemplate(), it would return defined in the constraint message template, eg. {javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}. If you have ResourceBundle file (provided with Bean Validation implementation or your own) then you can retrive message in a chosen language.

@Email is not Bean Validation built-in constraint, so it will not be trigger by JSF 2.0. Write your own  @Email constraint (or wrap that one provided by Hibernate Validator), so it will be recognized by Bean Validation.